# Why dont we consider centripetal force in the expression for net force in specific circular motion problems?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, home-experiment

I came across a problem in a circular motion which includes a stone tied to the end of a string. They asked for the net force at the highest point and the lowest point, but in the answer,[image] they never included the centripetal force why? (the correct option according to them is a but according to me it should be d)

Comment: It's strongly encouraged not to put images in order to make your question clearer. Furthermore, you should also provide additional details about your reasoning and why you think your solution is correct.

Comment: Hint: $T_1$ and $T_2$ ARE the centripetal force in the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that $T_1$ (for example) is not mentioned at all in the solution?  It's hard to answer without knowing what the solution looks like.

Comment: oh, that makes sense you mean tension is providing the centripetal force itself?

Comment: I'm new to this website, i didnt knew that I should not use images.

Comment: according to me, we should include tension, and centripetal force in the expression as I remember when I derived the expression for the velocity at the highest point (required to complete the whole circle without the string slacking), I used the tension and centripetal force in a single equation, So I think the answer should be a suitable expression including tension weight and centripetal force...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two forces acting on the stone - its weight $mg$ acting downwards and the tension in the string, which is $T_1$ acting upwards at the lowest point of the circle and $T_2$ acting downwards at the highest point of the circle.

The centripetal force is *not* a third force - it is just the net force that is required to keep the stone moving in a circle. Since we know that the stone is moving in a circle, the net force on the stone (the sum of its weight and the tension in the string, with appropriate signs) *is* the required centripetal force.

Answer (score 0):

Let's for get about gravity for a second:

$$ F = ma $$

*is*

$$ T = m \times \frac{v^2} R $$

The tension is the force, and the kinematic term is the mass times centripetal acceleration.

Another way to think about it, let's say you're accelerating at 6g in your top fuel funny car. Your seat applies a force to your body:

$$ F = 6mg $$

which equals your mass times acceleration:

$$ m \frac{dv}{dt} $$

If answer (d) were correct, then you would call that "force". It's not force, it mass times acceleration, and this is what $mv^2/r$ is also.